# How do you prove or disprove this recursive formula for the sum of powers of consecutive numbers?

Tags: geometry, summation

The formula in question is:

$\sum_{i=1}^n i^a = n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i^{a-1}) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(\sum_{j=1}^{i}(j^{a-1}))$

I stumbled across it while trying to find the formula for the cases of a = 2 and a = 3 with geometrical reasoning. I have checked and the formula holds for the cases of a = 1, a = 2, a = 3 and a = 4. I have been trying to prove it by induction, but I am really struggling. Can anyone show me how to prove it or disprove it?

[Representation(a=2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CZ9w.png)

Comment: It looks like a formula for summation by parts for $i^a=ii^{a-1}.$

Comment: Shouldn't the last $i^{a-1}$ in your formula be $j^{a-1}$?

Comment: $$\sum_{j=1}^{i}(i^{a-1})$$ have no sense. Edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $b_0=0.$ Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i(b_i-b_{i-1}) =a_nb_n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_{i+1}-a_i)b_i$$ For $a_i=i$ and $b_i=\sum_{j=1}^ij^{a-1},$ $i\ge 1,$  we get  $b_i-b_{i-1}=i^{a-1}$ and $a_{i+1}-a_{i}=1,$ hence
$$\sum_{i=1}^ni^a=\sum_{i=1}^ni\,i^{a-1}=n\sum_{j=1}^nj^{a-1}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^ij^{a-1}$$